# Energy required to break salt bridges in peptides and proteins

Tags: physical-chemistry, enthalpy, free-energy, entropy, proteins

Is there a way to calculate the energy required to break a salt bridge in a peptide or on the exposed surface of a protein in aqueous solution?  Is there any useful literature on this topic?  I'm looking to disrupt salt bridge interactions, and was wondering whether it would be feasible to do this by heating the sample, or whether infeasibly high temperatures would be required!

Thanks in advance for the help!